# Angular library using monorepo

Tags: angular, architecture, angular-library

I have the following folder structure and I want to implement an angular library inside the commons folder but I can't seem to make it work.

*monorepo\app\app_one\webapp\node_modules

*monorepo\app\app_two\webapp\node_modules

*monorepo\app\app_two\webapp\node_modules

*monorepo\commons\webapp\node_modules

Steps I have done so far.

*monorepo\commons* npm install -g @angular/cli

*monorepo\commons* ng new webapp --create-application false

*monorepo\commons\webapp* ng generate library some-design

*monorepo\commons\webapp* ng build some-design

Now after this point, I don't know what to configure. I have tried updating the app.module.ts inside the app_one but I can't import it, it seems like it can't find the file.